# How do web workers work in single core machines

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Can we reap the benefit of web workers, if we have single core machine? I have come across web workers are designed to work in multi-core processors environment.

Comment: Single cores are still able to execute multiple threads…

Comment: yes,always need to switch in between threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-threading can still be a valuable *organizational* tool even when it is not a tool to increase performance.

Consider a long calculation that isn't easily broken up into small pieces.  Running the calculation inside of a worker allows the operating system to perform scheduling for you.  The process runs in the "background", the user interface stays responsive, and you don't have to rewrite your code into a bunch of setTimeout() and setInterval() calls.